# Proper Way to Pull Changes from Github?

Tags: git, github, terminal, local

I'll preface this question with the fact I am a newbie, and I just want a clear answer as I'm confused when I go to the internet for help. That said, here is my question:

If someone submits a pull request, how do I pull those changes to my local machine to review before merging with master? Say the branch is named **feature1**.

Would "git pull feature1" on my local machine be sufficient?

I was thinking you could to hit "Merge" button through bitbucket and then "git pull origin master" to local, but there would be no way to check the code beforehand so that doesn't seem right.

Again, my apologies if this is a very beginner question. Just hoping for some clarity. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A pull request is a special ref in the format of `refs/pull/<number>/head`. Suppose there is a pull request `#29`. You can fetch it and create a local branch `p29` for it in the local repository by:

```
git fetch origin pull/29/head:p29
```

and then compare it with `master` by:

```
git diff master p29
```

If you are using a git GUI client or a user-friendly difftool, you can see the diff between the two branches in a more pleasant way.

When the review is done, you can remove `p29` by:

```
git branch -D p29
```

`p29` could be any other name you like as long as it's a valid ref name.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes pull request comes from forks, in order to get them you have to give url of of fork like you do this

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature1
git pull 'https://github.com/user/username/fork.git' feature1
```

if everything goes successfully, your 'feature1' branch has all the changes so now you can

```
git diff master
```

to see the difference between master and the pull request, if you like it you can merge it into master like this:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature1
```

and that's it... I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, it's best to use the following steps, considering you have a master branch and a feature branch that needs to be merged to master:

1. In your feature branch, make sure you comitted all your local changes.
2. Pull the feature branch from your remote. This will make sure that if other people worked on that feature, you don't miss those changes. Solve conflicts if any, and test if your feature branch still works (the application).
3. Pull the master branch from your remote.
4. Merge your master branch to your feature branch like `git merge --no-ff master`. No fast-forward makes sure you don't lose individual commits in your log.
5. Your feature branch is now equal to what you want to be the master branch: the master has been merged to the feature and you can now locally test if everything is alright.
6. If you are happy with the result, you can push your feature branch to your remote.
7. On the remote, you can create a pull request to merge your feature to the master branch. Because you tested your code + merge in step 5, you can be sure that the master branch will be alright. The Pull Request is now only for reviewing the code. You already tested it.